# How to scrape invisible part of HTML code

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, html-table

I need to scrape website https://e-mapa.net/ That's catastral records in Poland. To be precise, I would like to get the data from the element tagged by id 'gfi_0'. The thing is this element isn't accessible at once but only after clicking on any place on the map. Earlier it's not even present in html code (this part shows up atfer click). Below you cand find this part of html code.

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 270px; top: 170px; width: 330px; height: 350px; background-image: url(&quot;application/system/pandora/images/window_back.jpg&quot;); border: 1px solid rgb(68, 68, 85); background-position: 0px 0px; background-repeat: repeat; border-radius: 5px; z-index: 100051; display: block;">
<div style="position: absolute; left: 6px; top: 0px; right: 24px; height: 22px; padding-top: 4px; cursor: move; overflow: hidden; font-family: tahoma; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">Informacja&nbsp;o&nbsp;obiekcie</div>
<div style="position: absolute; inset: 26px 6px 6px; background-color: rgb(241, 244, 248); overflow: auto; border: 1px solid rgb(102, 102, 102); padding: 2px 5px 5px;">
<div style="position: relative;">
<div style="position: relative; height: 25px; background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204); margin: 6px 0px 4px; cursor: pointer;">
<div style="position: absolute; inset: 0px 24px 0px 0px;"></div>
<div style="position: absolute; top: 4px; left: 24px; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">Ewidencja&nbsp;gruntów&nbsp;i&nbsp;budynków</div>
<div style="position: absolute; left: 7px; top: 2px; width: 16px; height: 16px; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); display: block;">+</div>
<div style="position: absolute; left: 7px; top: 2px; width: 16px; height: 16px; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); display: none;">-</div>
<div style="position: absolute; top: 4px; right: 5px; width: 16px; height: 16px; background-image: url(&quot;application/images/print.png&quot;); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center;"></div>
</div>
<div style="position: relative; display: none;" id="gfi_0">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>101102_2.0005.unknown</title>
<table style="color: #000; font-size: 11px;">
    <tbody>
<tr><td>Identyfikator działki</td><td>101102_2.0005.unknown</td></tr>
<tr><td>Województwo</td><td>Łódzkie</td></tr>
<tr><td>Powiat</td><td>Poddębicki</td></tr>
<tr><td>Gmina</td><td>Pęczniew</td></tr>
<tr><td>Obręb</td><td>Drużbin</td></tr>
<tr><td>Numer działki</td><td>unknown</td></tr>
<tr><td>KW</td><td>brak informacji</td></tr>
<tr><td>Data publikacji danych</td><td>2019-10-25</td></tr>
<tr><td>Informacje dodatkowe o działce</td><td>Organem odpowiedzialnym za dane ewidencji gruntów i budynków jest Starosta Powiatu (ustawa Prawo geodezyjne i kartograficzne art. 7d pkt 1, Dz.U. z 2019 r. poz. 725).</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div
</div>
<div class="closeWindowButton" style="top: 4px; right: 2px;"></div>
<div class="collapseWindowButton" style="right: 19px;"></div>
</div>
```

I've tried

```
driver.get('https://e-mapa.net/')
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "gfi_0")))
```

or

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "gfi_0")))
```

but I get error the element isn't possible to locate

Help, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid this is not invisible part of html, but just the part that does not exist unless you click the required point on the map. When you click it, internal javascript detects where you click and generates a separate http request to https://e-mapa.net/application/system/get_feature.php with passing the params of your click. The response looks like this:

```
<body>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>301505_5.0001.846/1</title>
    </head>
    <table style="color: #000; font-size: 11px;">
        <tr>
            <td>Identyfikator działki</td>
            <td>301505_5.0001.846/1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Województwo</td>
            <td>Wielkopolskie</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Powiat</td>
            <td>Nowotomyski</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gmina</td>
            <td>Gmina Opalenica</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Obręb</td>
            <td>DAKOWY MOKRE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Numer działki</td>
            <td>846/1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>KW</td>
            <td>brak informacji</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Data publikacji danych</td>
            <td>2019-10-24</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Informacje dodatkowe o działce</td>
            <td>Organem odpowiedzialnym za dane ewidencji gruntów i budynków jest Starosta Powiatu (ustawa Prawo
                geodezyjne i kartograficzne art. 7d pkt 1, Dz.U. z 2019 r. poz. 725).
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

which is parsed and used as data source for new DOM node that has not been existing before the click.

So, in short, you have to click somewhere in your test and then you will get the access to the data you need.